# Как создать типизированный массив объектов?

Tags: java, массивы, коллекции, generics

Предыстория: пишу свою реализацию коллекции на основе массива (задание такое). И дошел до метода `toArray()`.

Есть классический массив:

`private E[] array;`

как его проинициализировать так что бы когда я возвращаю этот массив он был не `Object` а именно того типа который поступил на вход в класс.

Такой вариант при возвращении все равно возвращает `Object[]`

`array =(E[]) new Object[length]`

Просмотрел уже несколько лекций по дженерикам в джаве и основная суть ясна, но нигде не говорят о типизированных массивах.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Посмотрите, как это сделано в jdk, в `AbstractCollection`. Там два метода: `Object[] toArray()`, который создает и возвращает `Object[]` и `T[] toArray(T[] a)`, который заполняет переданный массив, если места достаточно, либо создает новый с таким же типом элемента через reflection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18581313/3212712) есть подробное описание проблемы на английском языке.

Вроде должно сработать как-то так:

```
public <E> E[] getArray(Class<E> clazz, int size) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    E[] arr = (E[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, size);

    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

При инициализации массива в Java вы изначально объявляете его тип. В памяти хранятся объекты именно этого типа, и присвоить внутрь него объекты другого типа, никак не получится. Скорее всего ваша проблема в том, что в каком то месте вы преобразовываете тип вашего массива в массив типа Object. Убедитесь что вы верно указали все типы переменных, а так же типы всех возвращаемых значение функций. Вот простой пример generic класса, работающего с массивом:

```
public class MyStructure<T>{

    private T[] array;

    public MyStructure(T[] array) {
        this.array = array;
    }

    public T[] getArray() {
        return array;
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание, на то что у функции `getArray()` указан тип `T[]`.

Comment: Проблема в том что конструктор у меня не принимает на вход массив как в вашем примере. Но все равно спасибо за полезный ответ) И стандартная функция toArray() имеет тип Object.

Comment: @Denis а от чего вы наследуетесь, что имеет функцию toArray() ?

Comment: Интерфейс Set()

Answer (score 1):

Информация о generic'a в java не доступна после компиляции. Все типы стираются и превращаются в Object, а type safe обеспечивается явным кастованием. Приведу пример. У нас есть метод:

```
final T field;

private T get() {
    return field;
}
```

После компиляции информация о типах сотрется и будет следующее:

```
final Object field;

private Object get() {
    return field;
}
```

А там, где вызывался метод будет следующее:

```
GenericClass<String>obj=new GenericClass<>();
String field= (String) obj.get()
```

Соответственно, конструкция вида `(T[])new Object[]` является вполне валидной.